# Select all links from a Html table using XPath (and HtmlAgilityPack)

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

What I am trying to achieve is to extract all links with a href attribute that starts with http://, https:// or /. These links lie within a table (tbody > tr > td etc) with a certain class. I thought I could specify just the the a element without the whole path to it but it does not seem to work. I get a NullReferenceException at the line that selects the links:

```
var table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='containerTable']");
if (table != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlNode item in table.SelectNodes("a[starts-with(@href, 'https://')]"))
    {
        //not working
```

I don't know about any recommendations or best practices when it comes to XPath. Do I create overhead when I query the document two times?

Comment: In my solution I provide a single XPath expression for all three different `<a>` nodes that should be selected. Also, it is more precise and efficient that finding all `<a>` nodes in the document (as another answer recommends -- //a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
 //tbody/descendant::a[starts-with(@href,'https://')
                     or
                       starts-with(@href,'http://')
                     or
                       starts-with(@href,'./') 
                      ]
```

**You will still have a problem**, unless you correct your code to reflect the fact that the the [`XmlNode.SelectNodes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx) instance method has a return type of `XmlNodeList`, not `HtmlNode`.

Answer (score 2):

The problems is that you are selecting the table and then immediately trying to select the anchors as if they were direct decedents. There are `tr` and `td` tags in the middle.

So, if you change your xpath to the following, things should work:

```
"tbody/tr/td/a[starts-with(@href, 'https://')]"
```

This will not work if your anchors are wrapped up in something else, so you could select *all* of the anchors in the current node set (i.e. table):

```
"//a[starts-with(@href, 'https://')]"
```

See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp) for more detail on xpath syntax.